# url-createobjecturl-no-longer-accepts-mediastream - after Chrome update on 14.12.2018

Tags: javascript, angularjs, createobject, mediastream, mediastreamsource

### Explanation of the problem and scenario.

I have a web app, that use a AngularJS component to take picture. However, after the last update on Google Chrome in 14.12.2018, this component stopped to work. I did search about the issue and i found out that all of the components that can do that stopped to work too, probably, because all of them used the method with mediastream argument that [was recently removed from the browsers](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2018/url-createobjecturl-no-longer-accepts-mediastream-as-argument/)

### The code

Looking in the source code of the component, we can see that they still use the `.createObjectURL` method passing `MediaStream` as argument, but this no longer is acceptable by browsers.

```
scope.enableCamera = function () {
return navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: true
},function (stream) {
    return scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.stream = stream;
        scope.isLoaded = true;

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!!!!!
    return scope.videoStream = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
    });
},function (error) {
return scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.isLoaded = true;
    return scope.noCamera = true;
});
});
```

### Objective

I would like to change the way the component works to get it working again, can someone help-me to do that?

Here is the link of the component on GitHub: https://github.com/onemightyroar/angular-camera

*Obs: I opened a issue there, but did not get any answer yet.*

Comment: Try this code file and see if it helps http://hfhphilly.healthyhomemanager.net/app/services/directives/vendors/camera/angular-camera.js